# Vimで横に並んでいる文字を縦一列に展開するには？

Tags: vim

以下のように、横に空白区切りで並んでいる文字列に対して、縦方向に展開したいのですが、このような動作をVimで簡潔に行えるコマンド等はありますか？

（この逆の、"縦方向に並んだ文字を横一列に並べる動作"はShift+jで行えるようですが、表題の動作を行う方法が調べても見つけられませんでした...)

よろしくお願いします。

**対象の文字列:**

```
a b c d e
```

**(期待する) 展開後の文字列:**

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`横に空白区切りで並んでいる文字列` の行で `:s/ /\r/g` するのでも良いと思います

Comment: 簡潔で良いですね、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

以下で空白を改行に置換できると思います。

```
:%!tr ' ' '\n'
```

`:`を入力した後、`%!tr ' ' '\n'`を入力します。

`%`は全行が対象となりますので、特定の行だけを対象とする場合は行番号に読み替えてください。
`%`を行番号１,行番号２とすれば行番号１から行番号２までが対象となります。

!`コマンド`の`コマンド`は行を標準入力とし出力結果で行を置き換えます。

Comment: trコマンドは知らなかったので、参考になりました！

Comment: 回答に追記しましたがtrはvimのコマンドではなく標準のコマンドです。!に続けて任意のコマンドが指定できます。

Comment: tr は Linux のコマンドなので、Windows 環境では使用できない点は注意が必要ですね。